# Do I need an isolated scope for this directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to write a very simple directive, which should transform:

```
<hello name="StackExchange"></hello>
```

into:

```
<hello name="StackExchange"><span ng-click="alert('StackExchange')">Hello!</span></hello>
```

The parent scope would have an `alert()` function. This is the code I've got working:

```
angular.module('hello', []).directive('hello', function () {
    return {
        scope: { name: '=' },
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<span ng-click="this.$parent.alert(name)">Hello!</span>'
    };
});
```

Is it possible to do this without creating a new isolated scope?

Comment: Is this really working? It shouldn't, as there is no `alert` function in the isolated scope.

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sb_satchitanand/69nMU/)
Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @tasseKATT: Read about AngularJS scope inheritance. The child scope has access to the properties of the parent scope.

Comment: No, not when using isolated scope. `The 'isolate' scope differs from normal scope in that it does not prototypically inherit from the parent scope`

Comment: @tasseKATT: Correct. I will update my question to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using an isolated scope, you could just create a new scope that has access to the parent scope.

```
angular.module('hello', []).directive('hello', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        template: '<span ng-click="alert(name)">Hello!</span>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.alert = function() {
                scope.$parent.alert(attrs.name);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmEaK/)

Comment: Adding a `link` function which functions as a wrapper around a method in the parent scope isn't my idea of simpler...